# updating useRef is not working for some reason

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

So the following code is an attempt to make two copies of a fetch request. One of them is for state and the other is being stored in as a ref.

I can't understand why the following snippet doesn't do what I need to it to which is add the backgroundColor prop to the ref array and then set the state to that array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
    setTimeout(() => {
        clone.current.map(item => ({...item, backgroundColor: 'blue'}))
        console.log(clone.current)
        setData([...clone.current])
        console.log(data)
    }, 4000)
}, [])
```

This is my first time using useRef, I'm trying to understand how to keep a copy of the state that won't change through renders. This is the whole code:

```
import React from 'react'
import './MyProjects.css'
import {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'

const MyProjects = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    let clone = useRef(null);

    async function fetchData() {
        await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?userId=1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            setData(json)
            clone.current = [...json]
        })
        // .then(setData(data.map((item) => ({...item, backgroundColor: true}))))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
        setTimeout(() => {
            clone.current.map(item => ({...item, backgroundColor: 'blue'}))
            console.log(clone.current)
            setData([...clone.current])
            console.log(data)
        }, 4000)
    }, [])    

  return (
    <div className='project-container'>
        {data.length > 0 && (
                <div className='data-container'>
                {data.map(item => (
                    <div key={item.id} style={{backgroundColor : item.backgroundColor}} onClick={() => {
                    }}
                    className='dataItem'>{item.title}</div>
                ))}
                </div>
        )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyProjects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Issues with the function:

1. Javascript map operation would create another array instead of updating current array, use for loop to update the ref.
2. It's not a guarantee that your fetch call will be executed before your settimeout call is executed, that's why you want to create another useeffect to process the data, you can create `dataLoaded` flag state and use that to just tigger this updating only once.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false);
async function fetchData() {
    await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?userId=1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        setData(json)
        clone.current = [...json]
        setDataLoaded(true);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
}, []);

useEffect(()=>{
    if(!dataLoaded) return;
    clone.current.map(item => ())
    for(let i = 0; i < clone.current.length; i++){
        clone.current[i] = {...clone.current[i], backgroundColor: 'blue'};
    }
    console.log(clone.current)
    setData([...clone.current])
    console.log(data)
}, [dataLoaded]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

1. array.map method does not mutate the array but create a new array

```
            const newArray = clone.current.map(item => ({...item, backgroundColor: 'blue'}))
            console.log(clone.current); // clone is not mutated
            console.log(newArray); // however the newly created array will contain backgroundColor = 'blue'
```

2. setData is async

```
            setData([...clone.current]) // set data is not immediate
            console.log(data) // the variable `data` binded here anyway won't reference the updated value
```

3. Your fetchData is asynchronous, your setTimeout is very prone to be buggy as you can't ensure that fetchData is completed

As a side note I don't really see the point of using a ref here since the data is already stored in a useState

Comment: I understand better now thanks. The idea behind useref is I want to update the background property whenever I click on the dataItem div. I cant do that with state since itll be reset with every click. I wanted something in the background that would keep track of it and not change with every render, hence the ref